# Send data from Jquery to Django html template

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, django-admin

how can I get a list of data from JQuery (Ajax) into the the Django HTML templates,
forexample in my file below, it gets the bac the data so now I want to send it in the `plan.html` :

`transitions.js`,

I have this :

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  (function ($) {
    'use strict';

    const transition_id = $(".trans_id").get(0).id;
    cooperationPartnerTransitions(transition_id)

     function cooperationPartnerTransitions(id)  {
        $.ajax({
          url: `/api/v1/accounts/cp_transitions/${id}`,
          type:'get',
          dataType: 'json',
          headers: {},
          success: function (data) {
            console.log("--->", data)
          }
        });
      }
  })(django.jQuery);
});
```

then, in my `plan.html` I have this :

```
{% extends 'admin/custominlines/change_form.html' %}
{% load static %}

{%block extrahead %}
  <script src='{% static "admin/js/transitions.js" %}'></script>
{% endblock %}
{% load i18n %}
 {% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
     {{ block.super }}
       {% if request.GET.edit %}
        <div class="submit-row">
             <div class="trans_id" id="{{ original.pk }}"></div>
            <input type="submit" value="custom" name="_transition-states">
        </div>
     {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I want to access the data from Jquery returned,

Comment: Your explanation of "loop the button" is really unclear of what you want to do with each request

Comment: @charlietfl, I have updated my question, I just want to get the returned data from jquery into the django template

Comment: From  jquery into the  `plan.html` file.

Comment: You need to consume it in the `success` where you currently log the data. Is the log not working? Still lacking details here

Comment: Neglect the button issue for now

Comment: The log is working, the data is coming, however I want to look for a way of accessing that data back in the template file , hope it's clear

Comment: The template doesn't exist any more....all you have in browser is a document. No, still not clear

Comment: So you mean, I can't utilize the parsed data from jquery into this file `plan.html` ?

Comment: Not as a file no. As part of the document you insert that template html into you can. So do you want to insert into `class="trans_id"`? Still missing details of the higher level explanation of what this request is for. The template only exists in your server code.  It's just elements in the document after sent to browser

Comment: The `transition_id` variable  is working , it just picks the id from `plan.html` , then I make a  request of which it returns back the data , so I wanted to use that in the same file `plan.html`

Comment: I want to get that data and use it again back in `plan.html`

Comment: We are going in circles. Use it to do WHAT?

Comment: That data contains number of buttons and their names we shall be having

Comment: Where you see the class `class="submit-row"` it's where am going to have dynamic buttons , so it will kinda be like a loop

Comment: Thats the explanation, but in this context I just want to get to know if I can get back the data in `plan.html`. or if there's a better process ?

Comment: Nobody can help you until you provide a more specific explanation of this. Hard to code *"kinda be like a loop"* which is virtually meaningless

Comment: I think I have explained very well, my problem, maybe someone else will read through and understand

Comment: But thanks for your time please.

Comment: Take a few minutes to read through [mcve]. Then update question with a data sample and expected results

Comment: I read that a long time ago please, lets give a chance to other people to read through, maybe there  suggestions will clarify the problem. Thanks

Comment: Hi, you can use `window.location.href="yoururl?parameter="+valuestosend` inside success function of ajax.